# delete[] keyword after declaring array using new causing error

Tags: c++, heap-memory, new-operator

I have the below code snippet.

```
int main()
{ 
    wchar_t *wTemp = new wchar_t[ArrSize];
    std::vector<char>  SourceVector;
    std::vector<std::wstring> DestinationVector;

    for (int i = 0; i < ArrSize; i++)
    {
        SourceVector.push_back(i);
    }

    int k = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SourceVector.size(); i++)
    {
        k += swprintf(wTemp + k, ArrSize, L"%u", SourceVector[i]);      
    }

    DestinationVector.push_back(wTemp);
    delete[] wTemp;

    return 0;
}
```

I am declaring a char array created using the "new" keyword. Since the new keyword has been used I have used the delete[] keyword for the created array at the end.

I have a SourceVector with some data. Data in SourceVector is stored in wTemp array and the array pointer is passed to DestinationVector to store the value in array to DestinationVector.

However, sometimes

```
DestinationVector.push_back(wTemp);
```

gives an error "Unhandled exception at 0x77408509 (ntdll.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x774458A0)."

Also, the line

```
delete[] wTemp;
```

gives the same error always.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In `k += swprintf(wTemp + k, ArrSize, L"%u", SourceVector[i]);` you keep using `ArrSize` for the max number of characters to write even after moving the starting point of `wTemp`. Think on that a moment and you'll probably see the bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always write at most `ArraySize` characters no matter where in the array you start via `wTemp + k`, that will lead to buffer overrun.

```cpp
k += swprintf(wTemp + k, ArrSize-k, L"%u", SourceVector[i]);
```

Is the correct call, but this will only reveal the true source of the error. `swprintf` appends `\0` (and actually writes only `n-1` chars) to each string and you did not leave a place for it in the array if the vector happens to be full.

Please do not use raw pointers, `std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]>` will work just fine as is safe. But it seems to me that you can just append to `std::wstring` directly and then add it to the destination vector.

Comment: This will still lead to problems as if the data does not fit in the space then a negative value is returned , which you should not add to `k`

Comment: @M.M Yes, you are correct, I was assuming that the source vector has always at most `ArraySize` elements as in the original code.

Comment: @Quimby the problem still happens in that scenario , the output is longer than the source due to printing as %u (and having a null terminator)